# How do I differentiate this in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following expression:

$$v=-r\omega \left( \sin\theta + \frac{r\sin(2\theta)}{2l \sqrt{l^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}}\right).$$

I need to find $\frac{\rm dv}{\rm d t}$, given that $\frac{\rm d\theta}{\rm d t} = \omega$ and $\frac{\rm d \omega}{\rm d t}=\alpha$. I need the entire process with steps. How do I do this in Mathematica? Note that $l$ and $r$ are constants.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you never used Mathematica before?

One way is to do the differentiation and then do the final replacement at the end

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
v[t] = -r*ω[t]*(Sin[θ[t]] + r*Sin[2*θ[t]]/(2*L*Sqrt[L^2 - r^2*Sin[θ[t]]]))
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now use the `D` command

```
D[v[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now do the final replacements

```
 %/. ω′[t]->α
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 %/. θ'[t]->ω[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These are the steps.

Here is the complete code in one cell

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
v[t]=-r*ω[t]*(Sin[θ[t]]+r*Sin[2*θ[t]]/(2*L*Sqrt[L^2-r^2*Sin[θ[t]]]))
D[v[t],t]
%/. ω'[t]->α
%/. θ'[t]->ω[t]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have never used Mathematica in my life, but I'm willing to learn about it. Is there any particular course I can do for this?

Comment: @HimanshuManglik a good book to start with it Wolfram's [elementary-introduction](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/3rd-ed/)  they have a free online version you can read.